# Is this site going to become Seasoned Advice? If so, when?

Tags: discussion

For those who aren't aware, the Web Apps beta graduated the other day and became Nothing to Install. Well, until it was reverted <24 hours later. There's lots of detail over on [this Meta Web Apps question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com/).

In various comments there, people claim that the name Nothing To Install isn't very good, and not-very-good names are a common SE theme. "Seasoned Advice" is singled out as the example of the good name that proves the bad name rule. It's been mentioned in [an MSO comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66443/public-service-announcement-ongoing-offsite-discussion-about-area51-graduates/66477#66477) by random♦, too.

So, is Food and Cooking beta going to turn into Seasoned Advice? If so, will there be a Food and Cooking [non-beta] intermediate phase?

Comment: So is the site getting ~38k visitors/day yet?

Comment: @DannyBeckett: Even if we were, that promise was withdrawn a very long time ago. I seriously doubt that we'll ever have a unique domain name regardless of traffic. Only a handful of sites are even getting branding. It's a long-dead issue which is why this is closed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is unfortunate, because cooking was the only site to produce a name that <s>wasn't beyond unspeakably horrible</s> was decent.

This isn't the community's fault, it's our fault. Naming isn't merely difficult, it is INSANELY OMGWTFBBQ HEAD-ASPLODINGLY difficult. Far, far harder than we predicted ... and I honestly don't think we considered *just how many sites* there would be. Sure, name 3 sites.. but naming TWENTY? FORTY? It's beyond broken to the point of mind-rending madness.

Thus, the new policy is this: **all sites will stick with their `topic.stackexchange.com` names until such time as they reach traffic levels roughly around what Server Fault currently has (~38k visitors/day).**

This reduces the naming insanity -- we have 25 sites and could have 50 within the next 12 months -- to a tolerable level.

So, feel free to pick a name, and if it's *good* (yours is) we'll try to use it in..

- site redirects (so `seasonedadvice.com` will redirect to `cooking.stackexchange.com`)
- site visuals (graphic logo tagline)
- site tagline text

Then eventually, as per above, it could morph into the actual (reserved) domain.

Comment: I assume, based on the strike through that 'wasn't' should have changed to 'was'?

Comment: I have two issues with the name. Short term, I find it very hard to refer non-technical users to the site. I've been thinking about trying to get the site a mention on the NPR program splendid table, but I haven't because I can't imagine them saying the name http://cooking.stackexchange.com on the radio and it generating any hits. Or the number of misses you'd get from a non-technical audience that would still put the www, which doesn't resolve to the site. Even linking a url is ugly with the current name, because there's a lot of "noise" in the name to a non technical user.

Comment: Long term, there's a serious issue if you try and rebrand after you're getting 35k+ visits a day. However, it sounds like you're saying that we do get the name in the site design and we do get a redirect URL. I think that would solve both of my issues with the naming schema. But does it solve your long term issue? Isn't webapps still going to be branded as and if it reaches mass get the url Nothing To Install? Or are you just assuming that if it gets 40k views a day, the name no longer matters?

Comment: @yossarian: Good point on the www thing. I forgot that people still did that.

Comment: @hobodave, I think that lies at the bottom of my issue with all this. Almost all of the sites and users so far are highly technical, with a ton of spillover from SOFU. Sub-domains work fine for those sites, as does the stack exchange name. But SE might as well be gibberish to a guitarist, cook, or photographer. Let alone trying to explain a sub-domain. But if they follow through on the redirects and using the name in visuals and tagline, I think that will take care of any issues. You just need a url to give out. It doesn't matter what the browser says once you're already there.

Comment: @yossarian - I think you're underestimating users.  Subdomains are hardly exotic or off-putting (like, say, .info might be).  Heck, every non-search Google property lives under a subdomain.  So do alot of Yahoo's.  That's a non-trivial chunk of all internet traffic right there, and the typical yahoo/google user is hardly "highly technical."

Comment: It's entirely possible that I'm wrong, @Kevin, but I've had the same experience as Aaronut: when I try and tell people about the site, I have trouble explaining it. When I tell people the url, they have that look that they've decided to stop listening because it's too complicated. I've started refering to it as "that cooking site I'm on" because that seems less awkward than cooking.stackexchange and the one I use has NO information about where the site actually is. It's weird to me, that there isn't a name by which I can refer to the site.

Comment: When someone refers to the yahoo search sub domain, they don't say "I went to search.yahoo.com", they say "I looked it up on yahoo" and the context makes the meaning clear. The delineation of topics to sub domains doesn't make that possible with the proposed stack exchange solution. If I refer to "finding the answer on stack exchange" I could be talking about any one of 100s (eventually?) of sites.

Comment: I suppose you could address this by calling it "Stack Exchange Cooking" like yahoo does with Finance (a well known brand), and that would help somewhat. However, if we're going to talk about bad names, lets look at "Stack Exchange" which is totally meaningless to me. Nothing about the name says "expert q&a site" to me. It also sounds very technical to me, and not where I'd expect to find photography or cooking. I don't really see how it's any better a name than "Nothing to Install".

Comment: @yossarian - We're not comparing Nothing to Install to StackExchange, we're comparing it to Cooking StackExchange (or StackExchange Cooking).

Comment: @Kevin, what I meant is that Stack Exchange is a bad name for all the same reasons that Nothing to Install is a bad name. So instead of having individual bad names, it's better to group everything under one bad name? I guess I'd probably agree with that logic, but it's not particularly satisfying. My issue remains, that the cooking site doesn't have a name, so I can't refer to it. How do I talk about something that doesn't have a name. And before you say it, no, I don't consider cooking.stackexchange to really be a name. Half of it is a descriptor and the other half is meaningless.

Comment: @yossarian - alright, if you're going to declare cooking.stackexchange not a name then I guess there's no point in continuing the discussion.  That's completely ridiculous, its like declaring you can't refer to C# because its *really* "C# .NET".

Comment: @yossarian you can still refer people to the site as "just go to seasonedadvice.com" and it will work. Isn't that what you are asking for? (and yes, when I used 'your' name it was just the first unusual name that popped into my head for some reason..)

Comment: It doesn't help that "stackexchange" is a bitch to spell + explain over the phone. But whatever - if "seasonedadvice.com" redirects, it's a non-issue, I can just use *that*. If anyone happens to notice the redirect and ask about it, I can just do the usual shrug + "oh, those crazy internets" thing.

Comment: @Jeff, yes. As I stated in my original comments, I think this approach is a pretty good compromise, because we still get branding and a redirect. Will only sites with "good" names get the redirects or will NTI get one too?

Comment: @Kevin, ok, maybe it is a name, but it's a terrible name. I can't call it "cooking" or "stack exchange", as your C# example suggests, because those are either inaccurate or undescriptive. And "cooking dot stack exchange" is also a terrible name, as 3/4ths of it don't mean anything (and 1/4 is a web artifice). Also, a url is not a name. A name can be a url, but that doesn't imply the opposite. So what would suggest we call it? Anyway, this is all probably moot, as the site is about to have a name, which I'm sure is what everyone will use, regardless of the URL.

Comment: @yossarian - "cooking" is inaccurate or non-descriptive?  Of a site about cooking?  Really?  I'll admit that StackExchange isn't an awesome name (or perhaps even a good name, I'd agree to OK-ish).  However, the real issue here isn't cooking centric.  Its how crazy hard coming up with names that are *better* than topic.stackexchange is.  Cooking might have done that, but then thats 1 out of 25.  That's a terrible success rate, one that *should* prompt a policy change.

Comment: @kevin, i believe what yossarian is saying is that you can't just call it "the cooking site", that's like implying i should tell everyone to visit amazon by calling it "that book site".  you can't refer to it in conversation as cooking.stackexchange because that is not memorable or meaningful - the cooking part is descriptive, but *nobody* is going to remember "stackexchange" once the conversation is over.  in fact, i asked a few non-tech people i know what they would expect to live on "stack exchange" and no two answers were the same, and none were even close to correct.

Comment: just to clarify, i think having the seasonedadvice.com url redirect here is a good compromise, i just wanted to throw in my voice as one more person who agrees with aaron and yossarian and knives, and explain my down-vote to the answer above.  i'd like to be more elaborate, but aaron's comments in the main thread are more detailed and eloquent than i could ever be.  but the short of it is, cooking.se is not the kind of URL you can share over the phone, in person, or on a radio show, no matter how much the se owners/moderators want it to be (and the votes on this thread loudly agree).

Comment: @stephen, thanks, that was it. Also, I **am** a tech person, and **I** don't know what to expect to live on "stack exchange" (I mean, obviously I do, because I'm familiar with it, but I wouldn't the first time I heard the name).

Comment: @kevin, Stephen pretty much nails it. Cooking is accurate in the context of stack exchange (and knowing what SE is), but I can't say "oh, I saw a great question on Cooking" because that's meaningless, just like saying "I saw a great question on Stack Exchange". Neither of those statements have much value, you have to use the combination, which is a lousy name for a community, heck it's not a name, it's a url (hence the 'dot'). But this is all really academic based on Jeff's original post, because we do get a name, which is far more important than a url.

Comment: @yossarian - "I found great results on Google."  What the heck is a  Google?  Of course non-techies don't know what StackExchange is yet, they didn't know what Twitter, Facebook, or Microsoft were either.  I read that entire argument as a pro-brand-building one, not an anti-StackExchange one.  I also take issue with @stephen's argument that we can't say "the cooking site."  That's the goal isn't it?  To be **the** site for cooking questions on the internet?  We aren't there yet, but why settle for "never gonna get there?"

Comment: @Kevin, I have expert-level cooking, non-techie friends.  As it stands right now, when I want them to contribute to the site, I can't say "that cooking site".  One day, perhaps, but that isn't going to help grow the community any now.  It could just as easily be referred to as "the cooking site" once it's SeasonedAdvice, but in the interim before it becomes Google-big, having a real name is vital in building membership, especially among experts who aren't necessarily techies like we are.  If someone told you, in person, to go to cooking.se.com vs SeasonedAdvice.com which would you remember?

Comment: Or, a better question might be, which would your mother or father remember - of course we, as techies, are going to remember and understand either :)

Comment: @stephen - in practice, if somebody tells me about a site I still google it (I'm terrible with names, and google corrects my screw ups).  I know my (non-techie) family members all just google everything.  Google is practically the command line of the internet.  Not to mention this only applies to oral communication, anything written down (email, IM, twitter) works just as well cooking.se versus seasonedadvice.  I suspect the computer use of the individual in question has an impact on whether or not they'd participate on a cooking website. :)

Comment: @Kevin, I understand and to an extent agree with what you're saying.  If they're savvy enough to participate they should be savvy enough to get to the domain somehow.  My concern is, just googling "cooking question answer site" brings up cooking.se as the last item on the first page; without a memorable name I don't know that my family would know to click that vs, say, ochef (which is first, and thus probably the only link my family would click).

Comment: An auxiliary concern is, how does one refer to the site in normal conversation, or in yossarian's example, on a radio show like The Splendid Table?  "That cooking site I'm on" could be epicurious, ochef, cooking.com.  I'm not being argumentative here - I'm actually looking to see how other people refer to it, because I had a problem this weekend trying to mention the site nonchalantly in conversation a few times.  Once the SeasonedAdvice redirect is up it will be moot, but for the time being I'm curious what other people are doing.

Comment: @Kevin: What about a compromise.  How about changing the subdomain to `seasonedadvice.stackexchange.com`?  That way you get your search engine juice, and we can at least pretend that it's really our name (it at least makes *some* sense when `seasonedadvice.com` redirects to `seasonedadvice.stackexchange.com` as opposed to `cooking.stackexchange.com`).  And we can actually have "seasoned advice" in the title and have that make sense to people.

Comment: @Aaronut - might work for cooking, but sucks for the rest of the network.  `nothingtoinstall.stackexchange.com` is literally the worst of both worlds, for example.

Comment: @Kevin: Fine, I'm not necessarily advocating a network-wide policy here; this would be similar to the suggestion someone made in the MSO thread, to be done if you accept the community's chosen name.  I'm sure that other non-suck names for other sites will spring up over time as well.  It would seem that you get everything you want this way, and the communities get at least *some* of what they want.

Comment: @kevin, if Google, twitter, and Microsoft are good names, then so is Nothing to Install. So I'm not really following your argument. But its all academic anyway.

Comment: @Kevin, so here's my question, kind of echoing Aaron two comments up - why does it have to be a catch-all solution?  Server Fault has an exception because it hit a certain threshold, so why couldn't cooking have an exception as well - sort of a middle tier.  If a community can't come up with a good name, they stay with the default webapps.stackexchange.com - but a popular community that agrees upon a good name can be seasonedadvice.stackexchange.com (for the reasons Aaron mentioned 4 comments up).

Comment: @yossarian - the argument is that we can build a brand, emphasis on **a** . If we're going to build one, it'd have to be StackExchange wouldn't it?

Comment: Ah, branding... Nothing like having a name you can trust when it comes to things you can use. *Wanders off to eat some delicious Unilever Food*

Comment: Love the Unilever example, @Knives; I've been trying for a while to think of a good example of a big conglomerate that lots of people buy from indirectly but nobody knows or cares about directly.  I'm not sure if people would readily buy ice cream from a company that once specialized in soap, if the connection weren't obfuscated behind a bunch of subsidiaries.

Comment: @knives would you rather eat cupcakes.unilever.com or nosalmonellaguaranteed.com ? That's how bad 99% of the suggested domain names are. Cooking's name is decent-ish, the rest are horrors from beyond the grave.

Comment: @Jeff: actually, my point is that even an established brand isn't worth *much* once you step outside of its established scope. Walk into any supermarket, and you'll encounter thousands of brands, hundreds of parent brands, few or none with any long-term relation to their manufacturers, who have *their own* brands that are exposed to an entirely different audience. SOIC is young enough to be stuck in the "soap company making margarine" role, but this too shall pass: if/when you succeed, you'll eventually find brands that don't expose the quirky name you picked for your back-end software...

Comment: @Jeff: I haven't seen every single proposed name, but probably one of the reasons that webapps' name was "horrible" is that web apps is not the most coherent/cohesive topic.  Compare with the Android SE 1.0 site, `forceclose.com` - every single Android owner is going to remember that.  In other cases, it's not that people can't come up with good names, it's that people can't come up with good .com names that aren't taken or squatted. I'll bet that if they weren't hamstrung by those restrictions, they'd have come up with better ones.

Comment: Also, I think people were set up to expect that the top-voted suggestion (or at least one of the top) would be chosen, which led people to try to invent names that would be palatable to the existing community rather than enticing to outsiders. That's why, for example, stats apparently picked the name "crossvalidated.com". If you actually came right out and said that you didn't care what people voted for and would make an editorial decision instead, they might be more creative. Not that any of this matters now, it just would have been nice if you'd said 2 months ago, "guys, these names *suck*."

Comment: I like the Seasonedadvice.stackexchange exception idea. I could see the Food Channel (Hypothetically) saying google Seasoned Advice, before I could see them saying go to cooking.stackexchange for good advice.

Answer (score 20):

I know nothing about this meta-discussion. But I hate the idea of leaving it as cooking.stackexchange.com. Have you ever tried to point someone to this site by word of mouth? It's impossible. I don't even bother and had been waiting for a new user friendly name.

Comment: As had most of us, I think.  Not that I want to discourage people from trying to promote the site the way it is, but the typical response so far has been "cooking dot *what*?  Never mind, I'll ask <name of friend or family member who cooks>."

Comment: @aaronut, Exactly. All the other stack exchange sites so far seem very techy, so I can see how those would work. But Cooking has such a different audience. Maybe the answer is that the community should get a name but maybe not provide it themselves?

Comment: Well we can still call it seasonedadvice.com verbally and it will still work, even if it *does* get redirected, you still have the name in the header area of the site.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, it's starting to look as though this thing might be stuck in "cooking..." limbo for an indeterminate amount of time. The SE Team hasn't, to my knowledge, come right out and said so... but there's been an awful lot of (cryptic, argumentative) hinting at it.

Which sucks, if true. Donno 'bout anyone else, but I've *really* been looking forward to recommending this site to family and friends, once it finally shakes free of the whole SE/A51 branding. I'm not really wild about trying to explain all that.

Comment: There's a good deal of geeks here do far, and that's great (I'm included in that group) but I don't think that's what the site wants in the long term. The name doesn't help at all.

Comment: @yossarian, by the way, Jeff mentioned you in a comment on [this post](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com/664#664); not really sure why. (EDIT: perhaps it was [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/74261/yossarian))

Comment: @lord, I'm going to give jeff the benefit of the doubt and assume he's making a literary reference to my namesake rather than taking weird potshots at active users.

Comment: @Lord: Catch 22