# Title and domain name?

Tags: discussion

A straightforward question that has probably already been answered before; it has however been a few weeks since I kept up with happenings.

Why is this site, now properly launched out of beta, still called "Food and Cooking"? I thought we had some good name suggestions - this is quite uninspiring at the moment! Also, what's with the *cooking.stackexchange.com* domain name still. *seasonedadvice.com* was a great name and seemed to be a pretty popular one all-round. Wha's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer (hopefully drama free) is that [we're not getting a domain name](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/). The URL will remain cooking.stackexchange.com. However seasonedadvice.com will redirect to cooking.se.com. So you can give out the new URL. According to the comments in [this answer by aaronut](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/861/new-design-launched/866#866), the site name will change to Seasoned Advice soon. While this isn't the URL people wanted, I think the most important aspect is that the site has a *name* which is far more important than a *url*, and there's a URL redirect that uses the site name.

If you really want to catch up on the drama (shouldn't you have better things to do on a Friday afternoon?), you can read about the start on [Webapps](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/624/webapps-stackexchange-com-versus-nothingtoinstall-com), [continuation on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66443/public-service-announcement-ongoing-offsite-discussion-about-area51-graduates), and our own input on [Cooking Meta](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/824/is-this-site-going-to-become-seasoned-advice-if-so-when). I assume this conversation went elsewhere too, but that's where I saw it.

Comment: Ouch- I hadn't seen any of these discussions. I had never heard of stack exchange before a friend referred me to cooking. It's hard to read these discussions and not become disillusioned.

Comment: @soba, I stand by my statement, you should have something better to do on a Friday! ;) This whole thing obviously could have been handled much better, but I think most of their reasoning makes sense.

Comment: @Soba: It is frustrating and several of us fought tooth and nail for the domain name, but as long the name itself is changed in the title, FAQ, etc., then we can market this as "Seasoned Advice", and if people ask about "Stack Exchange" after seeing references to it then we can say *afterwards* "Yeah, we're part of that network."  It's not totally unheard of; for example espn.com redirects to espn.go.com (too bad we don't have a parent domain like go.com).

Comment: Thanks for the info. This sounds less than ideal. (I mean, if this is the rule, why don't we have stackoverflow.stackexchange.com?.. Not that I'm suggesting it!) Still, could be worse. I notice that the title has already changed.